# C++ VS2010 Compiler doesn't use 'push' for a simple function call

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly, compiler-construction

I just started to learn a bit assembler from compiler output.

```
test(1);
```

This simple function call creates following asm output (compiled with x64)

```
000000013FFF2E76  mov         ecx,1  
000000013FFF2E7B  call        test (13FFF33C0h)
```

But why isn't it:

```
000000013FFF2E76  push        1  
000000013FFF2E7B  call        test (13FFF33C0h)
```

I thought a function parameter will be `pushed` to the stack and then `poped` in the function. Can somebody explain why VS prefer the top one?

Comment: passing by register is faster where possible.

Comment: MSVC always passes `this` in `ecx`. Also, arguments are passed by registers before using the stack. It's faster.

Comment: @Cicada that wasn't this though it was an int passed to a free function although that is interesting none the less.

Comment: @111111 I know. I was editing my comment.

Comment: @Cicada no worries, like I said that is interesting none the less.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because that's the ABI on x64 Windows.

On Windows x64, the first integer argument is passed in `RCX`, the second in `RDX`, the third in `R8` and the fourth in `R9`. The *fifth* and following are passed through the stack.

Because your function has a single argument, only `RCX` is used.

The compiler issued a write to `ECX` because all writes to 32-bit registers result in zeroing the higher part of the 64-bit register, and 32-bit immediates are obviously shorter than 64-bit ones (instruction cache anyone?).

Comment: Funnily it uses only `ecx` and not `rcx`.

Comment: @Cicada: it uses `rcx`, `mov ecx, IMM` actually means `RCX[0:31] = IMM; RCX[32:63] = 0`.

Comment: I know. I'm simply wondering *why* the compiler uses the `ecx` qualifier instead of `rcx`. EDIT: Oh, because it's an `int`. Derp.

Comment: test(unsigned long long value).. it still uses ECX but e.g. test(UINT64_MAX) would use RCX. Didn't know that the compiler is so clever^^

Comment: @Aurus: it's because the compiler doesn't care about the actual type here, it checks whether the *value* can be represented as a 32-bit immediate.